# Remove html tag - JSDOM

Tags: node.js, jsdom

```
 <div class="">
    <figure class="">
        <a href =""> <img src= ""></img> </a>
        <figurecaption> Advertisemnt</figurecaption>
     <figure>
</div>
```

considering above html want to remove root node if figurecaption contains 'Advertisment' Ttext using JSDOM .How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use cheerios to work with html tag. Check it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio